# Vue + axios returns undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have `app.js` importing axios and VueAxios as:

`Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);`

Then calling my component:

`Vue.component('api-call', require('./components/PostComponent'));`

In my `PostComponent` I have a simple axios get as follows:

```
<script>
    export default {
        // name: "PostComponent"
        data() {
            return {
                post: {},
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getPosts: () => {
                console.log('started');
                //let that = this;
                let uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
                this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.getPosts()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Since I want this executed right at the start of the component loading I am using `mounted` (why Vue don't have a constructor baffles me, even react passed on the `isMounted` pattern.)

What am I doing wrong?

thanks,
Bud

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use arrow function for methods declaration.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods

> Note that you should not use an arrow function to define a method
> (e.g. plus: () => this.a++). The reason is arrow functions bind the
> parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and
> this.a will be undefined.

These are the 2 ways to properly define a method

1.

```
        getPosts: function() {
    
        }
```

2. (if you can use ES6)

   ```
        getPosts() {

        }
   ```